# where is war exploded in Liferay 7 tomcat after getting copied in osgi folder

Tags: liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I deployed a portlet in liferay 7 and it got deployed successfully and was available for use. I want to replace the jsp file, in earlier version I could see my application in tomcat/webapps folder and replace it quickly.
Now I am unable to locate the exploded war in liferay 7. I can only see the war in osgi/war folder.
Can someone help me with that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Liferay IDE team is working on a feature like this for Liferay 7.0: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-3743. Please vote for the issue if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

While I mostly agree with what Olaf wrote, I do understand the need to be able to make changes in JSP files and try them quickly during development. I'm afraid I don't have the solution for that yet.

However, let me answer the question you asked:

> where is war exploded in Liferay 7 tomcat after getting copied in osgi folder

It is NOT *(at least not the way it was done by application servers)*! When you deploy a WAR file in Liferay 7, it will automatically (on the fly) convert it into OSGi bundle and install it in OSGi runtime. This way now Liferay is fully in charge of deploying plugins and does not need to rely on various application servers.

PLEASE NOTE: Every bundle has it's own state folder. In Liferay those are in `<LIFERAY_HOME>/osgi/state`. If you know the bundle ID you can easily find it. It may be (I haven't checked) that you'll find some JSP files there. The reason I'm writing this is to warn you (in case you figured it yourself) to **NEVER modify bundle's state folder** manually. Doing so may brake the whole environment. In worse case scenario you may have to redeploy everything in clean environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on behavior like this. In previous versions it was the task of the application server to compile changed JSPs at runtime. However, this is bad practice in production systems and totally screws up your maintainability. If you need to update some UI code frequently, I'm suggesting you change your implementation to utilize ADT (Application Display Templates), e.g. through Freemarker or Velocity. Those are meant to be updated at runtime, where the JSP updates were a side effect of Tomcat's default (development friendly, production hostile) configuration

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think will have to get used with the new ADT thing. I agree JSP's were a side effect for timcat